# Jquery jump on a div and getting down

Tags: jquery, html, css, bounce

I am trying to create a smooth jump on to a div and get down of the div once div is completed. Could some one guide me on smooth jumping effect with jquery.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/PzS68/6/)

```
$(document).keydown(function(pk){
var pos = $('#box').position();

  if(pk.keyCode == '37')
  {
      $('#box').css('left',pos.left - 5 + 'px');
  }
    if(pk.keyCode == '38')
  {      
     $('#box').css('top',pos.top - 5 +'px');
  }
    if(pk.keyCode == '39')
  {
           $('#box').css('left',pos.left + 5 + 'px');
  }
    if(pk.keyCode == '40')
  {
         $('#box').css('top',pos.top + 5 + 'px');
  }
    if(pk.keyCode == '74')
  {
         $('#box').css('top',pos.top - 55 + 'px');
  }

  });
```

Comment: You want the "jump" to be like an animation?

Comment: Yes sir, jump, move and get down like Mario game jump.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('#box').css('top',pos.top - 5 + 'px');
```

to:

```
$('#box').animate({'top':pos.top - 5 + 'px'}, 400);
```

and so on... That way the change in position will be animated.
To create the effect of the player falling down after jumping you can use this code:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#box').animate({
        'top': pos.top + 'px'
        }, 90);
    }, 400);
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/PzS68/8/)**

### Customization

Change `400` to whatever you want (it's the time the animation should take, measured in ms).